# Node.js heap memory limit for single object

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management, v8

Does v8 have limits on the heap allocations for single objects?

`a = new Array(1024*1024*102)`

fails on node command-line with

`FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory`

Also, this fails with the same error when run as a script

`node --expose-gc --nouse-idle-notification  --max-old-space-size=8192`

`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory`

```
var util = require('util');
o = {};

while(1) {
    o["hahahahahaha" + String(ctr)] = ctr;
    ctr++;

    if (ctr % 100000 === 0) {
        console.log(util.inspect(process.memoryUsage()));
        if (ctr % 10000000 === 0) gc();
    }
}
```

Last output:

`{ rss: 1009557504, heapTotal: 993408824, heapUsed: 964980592 }`

However,

```
var a = [];
while(1) {
    var o = {};
    o["hahahahahaha" + String(ctr)] = ctr;
    a.push(o);
    ctr++;

    if (ctr % 100000 === 0) {
        console.log(ctr);
        console.log(util.inspect(process.memoryUsage()));
        console.log();
        if (ctr % 10000000 === 0) gc();
    }
}
```

is just fine

`{ rss: 5466140672, heapTotal: 1091224368, heapUsed: 1070460592 }`

Edit:

`node -v`

`v0.10.25`

`uname -a`

`Linux 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Edit 2:
Even this works!
It seems that v8's limit applies to number of properties an object can have?

```
while(1) {

    if (!o["hahahahahaha" + String(Math.floor(ctr/1000000))]) {
        o["hahahahahaha" + String(Math.floor(ctr/1000000))] = {};
        console.log(Object.keys(o))
    }
    o["hahahahahaha" + String(Math.floor(ctr/1000000))][String(ctr)] = ctr;
    ctr++;

    if (ctr % 100000 === 0) {
        console.log(ctr);
        console.log(util.inspect(process.memoryUsage()));
        console.log();
        if (ctr % 10000000 === 0) gc();
    }
}
```

`{ rss: 2474512384, heapTotal: 2466405768, heapUsed: 2431583008 }`

Also, I found this:
https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects.h#L2928

I wonder if it's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that there are hard-limits put on the maximum size of strings, objects and arrays.
The limts are a remnant of the old garbage collector.
Here is the relevant ticket:

https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3505

Comment: Is there a way to change this limit, turns out on my laptop, this limit is very small, ex. `n = 33000000`, `new Array(n).fill(0)`.