# Object memory storage in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just try this code on both **Chromium** console and **Node.js** console:

```
var map = {};
for(var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
   var key = '' + Math.random();
   map[key] = true;
}
var time = (new Date()).getTime();
console.log(map['doesNotExists']);
console.log((new Date()).getTime() - time);
```

In a browser: several seconds.

In Node.js: a few milliseconds.

So, I suppose Node.js use `HashMap` storage and Webkit does not. Is it correct?

I wonder if Node.js store all objects (even small objects) this way. Do you know if there is a storage rule depending on the size for objects in Node.js?

---

## Update 2017-05-02

This is no longer true, now, the difference is not significant. My guess is storage in a `HashMap` way has been introduced since 2015.

Comment: I'm not sure using the Chrome console is a realistic evaluation of performance...

Comment: This looks like what you're after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231808/node-js-heap-memory-limit-for-single-object

Answer (score 0):

Even though it feels very console-like...The **Chromium console is a software program presenting a graphical user interface for you, it is in fact not the console**.  This program is running your commands behind the scenes.  In particularly, they do quite a bit of pre & post processing of the I/O to make it pretty, collapsable if it's an object, etc -- all of that detection, comparison, even color formatting takes cycles that add up.

All that to say, there is a lot more going on there than just hitting the underlying V8 Engine.

On top of that, all of this is really limited by the browser itself -- think of it a lot more like you saying, "Hey, Chrome - while you're doing whatever else you've got in other tabs -- also fit this in."  Finally, you're also going to hit memory and timeout limits governed by the browser.  **All of this make it an unfair compare!**

While Node uses V8 for JS interpretation, it's not going to be doing any of that nonsense for all of your 10 million iterations -- which I would expect would absolutely speed up the NodeJS run...and it doesn't really have anything to do with either storing object a different way.

Comment: I was not comparing micro-seconds difference, there was a huge gap, and there is only 1 console.log of undefined and 1 console.log of a number, if the storage is a HashMap way as in Nodejs, it should'nt be so long. But this is no longer true in 2017, the access is now as fast as in Nodejs.