# Is there a limit on the number of members in a Javascript Set()? Or is this a bug in V8

Tags: javascript, out-of-memory, v8

Here's some simple Javascript code that repeatedly adds integers into a Set:

```
var i;
var limit = 1 << 24;
var s = new Set();

for (i = 0; i < limit + 10; i++) {
    s.add(i);
    if (i >= limit - 10) console.log ("Set size is now " + s.size)
}
```

When the set size grows to 2^24 exactly (which I've called "limit"), there is a

```
FATAL ERROR: invalid table size Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

The process isn't anywhere near running into an actual memory limit, and it's really suspicious that this occurs at exactly 2^24 elements. This happens using node.js, or if I run it inside Chrome. I've tried it on both Windows and Mac OSX (both 64 bit), and it seems to hit the wall at 2^24 elements when you store other more complex things in Set()s. I think Map() and its ilk all have the same issue.

I couldn't find anything about this limit in the documentation. Is it a bug?

Comment: Related question: [Node.js heap memory limit for single object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231808/node-js-heap-memory-limit-for-single-object) and the referenced Chrome bug report.

Comment: You may call it a bug but the V8 developers (and node core developers) have consistently closed them as not-a-bug. They are still unconvinced that there are valid use cases where one should use that much memory in a javascript app. But I believe it's an artificial limit. It's just a number or constant defined somewhere. Feel free to compile node yourself if you need to increase that number.

Comment: Yeah, and I've heard that John Von Neumann once said that no good programmer would ever need more that 4096 words of memory. In this case I'm not really using a huge amount of memory--this data structure shouldn't occupy more than a few hundred MB of memory with the way Set() is implemented (I've checked), and you can certainly use much more memory than that in a Javascript app.