# Artificial performance limits in V8 / nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

V8 is capable of wrangling a lot of memory with use of `--max-old-space-size`. I regularly use node for tasks which require 10GB+, it's great - memory is cheap and it's much faster than reading/writing from/to disk.

Where I run into trouble, however, is when trying to create very large individual arrays/maps/objects. I end up with error messages like this:

```
FATAL ERROR: invalid table size Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

And this:

```
RangeError: Invalid array length
```

In both cases, it's not that my computer can't handle it, or that I've ran out of memory - it's because there are some insidious artificial limits hiding in V8.

To get the range error, throw this in your terminal: `node -e "new Array(5*1000*1000*1000)"`

And to get the invalid table size error: `node -e "(new Array(200*1000*1000)).fill(1)"`

These artificial limits are well known ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971500/is-there-a-limit-on-the-number-of-members-in-a-javascript-set-or-is-this-a-bu), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231808/node-js-heap-memory-limit-for-single-object)), and are apparently due to some old garbage collector code that the V8 team <s>is scared of touching</s> knows will take a lot of work to fix (see [chromium bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3505)).

---

#### Question:

To someone *who knows the V8 and nodejs roadmaps well*: Will these limits ever be lifted? How long could we expect to wait, roughly?

Please note that I understand patterns for lower memory usage like streaming and I know that nodejs and V8 weren't made for "big data" stuff - this question isn't about how to optimise my memory usage and the like. Just curious about the V8 and nodejs roadmaps in terms of these artificial limits.

Comment: You seem to have done as much as you could of explaining the use case in the bugreport you have made, but I don't really get why the question here? Is it to get support from the community for this bug? As they suggest inside the topics you have linked to, if it annoys you feel free to have a go at removing those limits. If you have a good enough implementation, why not supply the fix for it yourself?

Comment: My hope is that someone close to the v8 and nodejs projects (and who thus has good knowledge of the roadmaps and goals) will be able to give the nodejs/js community some information relating to the road map in terms of these artificial limits. I did consider posting in the nodejs repo, but ended up posting here because it touches on V8 too, and isn't strictly a bug/issue. I don't think your comment about implementing it myself is relevant to my question.

Comment: Though I like how you presented your arguments in your question, I don't think it is on-topic for SO itself. At most you can get community support and yes/no answers. If you have a use case and V8 doesn't support that use case, maybe you should look into other languages that do support your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts :) These limits are pretty easy to get around for my use cases by using simple abstractions (chaining arrays, making meta sets/maps, using buffers, binding native stuff etc.) - though it does discourage people from using JS for big stuff. It was mainly a question of curiosity - and perhaps not one perfectly suited to SO as you say.

Comment: Disk operations aren’t that slow these days with SSD disks... or (even cheaper *and* faster) a [RAID 0 array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_0) of portable hard disks connected via an USB 3.0 hub. My credentials: being a happy user of said RAID 0 array ☺.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

V8 developer here. In short, it's not on the roadmap, sorry.

We're aware that having size limitations on arrays and strings is unfortunate. However, raising the existing limits is going to be a lot of effort. We'd like to do it at some point, but it doesn't have priority right now. (That's pretty much what the bug you've referenced sums up to -- we're not so much *scared* of it, it's just non-trivial because it's *not* just an "insidious artificial limit", and we don't have time for it given other priorities.)

It's not *just* a question of effort either, there are also technical considerations. Supporting arbitrary lengths, while possible, would make certain operations slower. We recognize that *some* use cases would really benefit from this increased flexibility, but *other* use cases benefit from the speed that comes from a simpler and faster underlying implementation. Finding the right balance is not obvious. Also, we still have to support 32-bit platforms, where the pointer size puts rather low limits on e.g. object sizes, and we as much as possible want to have the same behavior regardless of underlying hardware/OS. That's part of the point of having a JavaScript VM in the first place...

Speaking of JavaScript: The ECMAScript spec defines that `new Array(n)` throws a `RangeError` whenever `n != ToUint32(n)`. `5*1000*1000*1000` is not a uint32. So this particular case is actually required behavior; if V8 were to support such arrays, it would be violating the spec.

Comment: Thanks for giving us the full rundown! Hadn't considered that removing these limits could actually cause V8 to run slower, or that the `2*32` was what was causing that RangeError. Thanks again 